# Using getchar() and malloc() together

Tags: c

I found a C Program whose purpose is to input a string while using dynamic memory allocation.

However I am having difficulty understanding the logic behind it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 10

int main(void)
{
char *A;
int max_int=0;

printf("Enter max string length: ");
scanf("%d",&max_int);

while ((getchar())!='\n');
A=(char *)malloc(max_int+1); //room for null char

printf("Enter string: ");
fgets(A,max_int,stdin);
}
```

What is the purpose of  `while ((getchar())!='\n');` ? It seems redundant to me, since your only inputing a number before it gets called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while ((getchar())!='\n');
```

The above line is used to flush anything on the line not read by `scanf`, for example non-digits and spaces, so the next input starts in a new line.

Also:

- `scanf`-call should check the number of assigned matches (0 matches *is* possible.
- the result of `malloc` should never be cast (that just hides bugs).
- the result of `malloc` should be checked for `NULL`. (Warning: **Undefined Behavior**)
- `fgets` expects the buffer length and guarantees 0-termination. Passing one less means you get a shorter string.

Comment: Ok Im honestly confused. fgets should call the *next* thing from input, and ignore anything before it which logically shouldn't exist. Unless your implying the number is still on stdin. Also I've been told by my professor casting is required for all uses of DMA. Its fundamental, especially for structs and typedefs

Comment: fgets gets the number from stdin, but neither any cruft nor the newline following. Also, what do you mean with "DMA"?

Comment: That's exactly it. The `scanf` call reads a (possibly signed) decimal integer, and leaves anything following it (such as a newline) waiting for the next input call. Your professor is mistaken; casts are *not* required for dynamic memory allocation. The `void*` value returned by `malloc` is implicitly converted to the target pointer type.

Comment: @KeithThompson "The void* value returned by malloc is implicitly converted to the target pointer type." - is this a new C thing? Sorry to sound naive

Comment: The rule for casting is, don't do it. If you have to, be absolutely sure about what you are doing, because you just said the compiler to shut up and do what it is told (that often results in Undefined Behavior). And C implicitly converts from and to `void*` since invention of `void`.

Comment: @BDillan: No, it's not new, it goes back to the 1989 ANSI C standard. (If your compiler complains that a cast is required, you're probably using a C++ compiler.)

Comment: You are not using a C compiler **or** you have not included the proper header, in which case casting is really bad. (Should give a warning about implicit function definition though...)